# java n-ary tree depth

Tags: java, tree

here is my tree node class:

```
public class Generalization extends Class_object {
private List<Generalization> superClasses;
private List<Generalization> subClasses;

public boolean isRoot() {
    return superClasses.size() == 0;
}

public boolean isLeaf() {
    return subClasses.size() == 0;
}

// path length to root
public String getDIT() {
    return Integer.toString(recuDIT(this));
}

public int recuDIT(Generalization g) {
    if (g.isRoot())
        return 0;
    else {
        int maxLength = 0;
        for (Generalization gen : superClasses) {
            maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, recuDIT(gen));
        }
        return maxLength + 1;
    }
}

// path length to leaf
public String getCLD() {
    return Integer.toString(recuCLD(this));
}

public int recuCLD(Generalization g) {
    if (g.isLeaf())
        return 0;
    else {
        int maxLength = 0;
        for (Generalization gen : subClasses) {
            maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, recuCLD(gen));
        }
        return maxLength + 1;
    }
}
}
```

each node have its parent node and child node. But when I execute program, it give me *stackoverflowerror* in both recursive function (CLD and DIT). 
Could anyone tell me why they loop infinitely?
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are always starting at the exact same spot. You have to move forward with the list. Right now you are always going to the first object in the list and calling a recursive call which is doing the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Generalization {
    private List<Generalization> superClasses;
    private List<Generalization> subClasses;

    public Generalization(){
        superClasses = new ArrayList<Generalization>();
        subClasses = new ArrayList<Generalization>();
    }

    public boolean isRoot() {
        return superClasses.size() == 0;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return subClasses.size() == 0;
    }

    // path length to root
    public String getDIT() {
        return Integer.toString(recuDIT(this));
    }

    public int recuDIT(Generalization g) {
        if (g.isRoot())
            return 0;
        else {
            int maxLength = 0;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < g.superClasses.size(); i++){
                maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, recuDIT(g.superClasses.get(i)));
            }
            return maxLength + 1;
        }
    }

    // path length to leaf
    public String getCLD() {
        return Integer.toString(recuCLD(this));
    }

    public int recuCLD(Generalization g) {
        if (g.isLeaf())
            return 0;
        else {
            int maxLength = 0;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < g.subClasses.size(); i++){
            maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, recuCLD(g.subClasses.get(i)));
            }
            return maxLength + 1;
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    Generalization root = new Generalization();

    Generalization ch1 = new Generalization();
    Generalization ch2 = new Generalization();

    root.subClasses.add(ch1);
    root.subClasses.add(ch2);

    Generalization gc1 = new Generalization();
    Generalization gc2 = new Generalization();
    Generalization gc3 = new Generalization();

    ch2.superClasses.add(root); 
    ch2.subClasses.add(gc1);
    ch2.subClasses.add(gc2);

    ch1.subClasses.add(gc3);
    ch1.superClasses.add(root);

    Generalization ggc1 = new Generalization();

    gc3.subClasses.add(ggc1);
    gc3.superClasses.add(ch1);

    gc2.superClasses.add(ch2);
    gc1.superClasses.add(ch2);

    ggc1.superClasses.add(gc3);

    System.out.println(ggc1.getDIT());
    System.out.println(root.getCLD());



}
}
```

Without knowing if I am setting the tree up correctly or really testing that much, this works for me. The main issue was you were using the classes recuDIT/CLD and not the Generalization object g in the method. So you were constantly looping through the same list recursively without moving on from the first index. I also changed your for each loop to a for loop because it was easier for me to see and debug.

Other than that, this gives me 3 for the length to root and length to leaf which I believe is correct.